# SwiftUI run function on losing focus TextField

Tags: events, swiftui, textfield

I want to run some function whenever a textfield loses focus.
Textfield already has onEditingChange and onCommit but I want to run a validation function once the user leaves the textfield.

Something **similar** to what **onblur** does for web without cluttering any other view on screen.

Comment: what's wrong with `onEditingChanged`? I'll pass you `false` when user leaves the text field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 15, `@FocusState` and `.focused` can give you this functionality. On iOS 13 and 14, you can use `onEditingChanged` (shown in the second `TextField`)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var text2 = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text goes here", text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    print("Lost focus")
                }
            }
        TextField("Other text", text: $text2, onEditingChanged: { newValue in
            print("Other text:",newValue)
        })
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something similar for IOs 13 or less?

Comment: Updated my answer -- `onEditingChanged` works in iOS 13 and 14